# Pods.xcconfig file - why is it missing and is it necessary?

Tags: cocoapods

This guide mentions a Pods.xcconfig file:

https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html

However, I can't find it in any of the directories for my latest project (and yes, I'm using CocoaPods for this project).

A previous project where I used Pods had this file under `Pods/` however looking there I can't see it.

Question 1: any idea why this is missing?

QUestion 2: do I need it?